# Combine two algorithms in one float

Tags: spacing, floats, minipage, algorithms

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \Function{Foo}{parameters}
                \State{Do something}
                \State{\Return result}
                \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{Algorithm 1}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \Function{Foo}{parameters}
                \State{Do something}
                \State{\Return result}
                \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
            \caption{Algorithm 2}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Some text.
Then comes the next algorithm.
\pagebreak
\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{Foo}{parameters}
        \State{Do something}
        \State{\Return result}
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Algorithm 3}
\end{algorithm}

And again some text.

\end{document}
```

I want to combine two (or potentially more) algorithms in one floating object. The only solution for this that I found, is to use two minipages and add a new algorithm environment within. The problem with the solution is that it adds some space above the algorithm. This is clearly visible when compiling the document. There is some space above combined algorithms in the left column. The single algorithm in the right column appears correctly?

How can I remove the additional space or is there any better solution to combine two algorithms in one float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `\baselineskip` to remove.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tp]
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Foo}{parameters}
    \State{Do something}
    \State{\Return result}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm 1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Foo}{parameters}
    \State{Do something}
    \State{\Return result}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm 2}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

Some text.
Then comes the next algorithm.

\vfill
\pagebreak

\begin{algorithm}[tp]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Function{Foo}{parameters}
  \State{Do something}
  \State{\Return result}
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm 3}
\end{algorithm}

And again some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need `\noindent`, because the indentation is set to zero inside `figure`.